# Transposing a set of rows as column in a Flex Data Grid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I have an array like the following one

```
public var sal:Array=[
     {empNo:1001, sal:1000, exp:400},
     {empNo:1002,    sal:3000, exp:240},
     {empNo:1003,    sal:1000, exp:452},
     {empNo:1004,    sal:5000, exp:348},
     ......
     {empNo:1550,    sal:2000, exp:330},

     ];
```

I need to show data using a 3 row flex data grid where the first row will display empNo, the second row will display corresponding salary(field sal), and the third row will display Expenditure (field exp).

Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hi can you elaborate more what do you mean by this "3 rows flex data grid"

Answer (score 0):

Actually I meant to say that data will come into a dataGrid in a format as given below 
Row 1:->Emp No  1001    1002    1003
Row 2:->Sal 1000    3000    1000
Row 3:->exp 400 240 452

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" initialize="formatData()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            var dp:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection();

            private function formatData():void
            {
                var salArray:Array=[{empNo: 1001, sal: 1000, exp: 400}, {empNo: 1002, sal: 3000, exp: 240}, {empNo: 1003, sal: 1000, exp: 452}, {empNo: 1004, sal: 5000, exp: 348}];
                var i:int=0;
                var empNo:Object=new Object();
                var sal:Object=new Object();
                var exp:Object=new Object();
                var columns:Array = new Array();

                for (i=0; i < salArray.length; i++)
                {
                    empNo["col"+i]=salArray[i].empNo;
                    sal["col"+i]=salArray[i].sal;
                    exp["col"+i]=salArray[i].exp;
                    var advancedDataGridColumn:AdvancedDataGridColumn=new AdvancedDataGridColumn();     
                    advancedDataGridColumn.dataField="col"+i;
                    columns.push(advancedDataGridColumn);
                }

                dp.addItem(empNo);
                dp.addItem(sal);
                dp.addItem(exp);
                adg1.columns=columns;
                adg1.invalidateDisplayList();
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGrid x="40.5" y="163" id="adg1" designViewDataType="flat" dataProvider="{dp}">      
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>

</mx:Application>
```

i think this is what you asked :)